# Изменить фон на сайте

Tags: php

Вот скажите у меня есть код

```
 <html>
<title>
<body>

Страница правил которым мы все должы следовать
</title>

<?php

$SITED = "Раскрутон";
echo "
<center><h1>Проект < font color= red ><b>$SITED</b></font> предоставляет услуги раскрутки, при соблюдение следующих правил</h1></center>
 <p>1.1 Если вы увидели что сайт в серфинге разрушает фрейм, или ваш антивирус обнаружил вирус, то подайте на сайт жалобу, я его обработаю и проверю</p>
 <p>2.2 Если вы добавили сайт с порнографией, это ваш страх и риск, я буду <font color = red><b>банить</b></font> такие сайты</p>
 <p>2.3 Если вы нашли какую-нибудь ошибку в сайте прошу напишите об этом мне <font color = red>Jack-Sparrou@yandex.ru</font></p>

 <p><center><h1>О сайте</h1></center></p>
 <p> Сервис <b>$SITED</b> предоставляет услуги <font color = red>БЕСПЛАТНОЙ</font> раскрутки, ниже ответы на распространнёный вопросы</p>
 <p><font color = red>Вопрос:</font> Я добавил сайт с реферальной ссылкой, но в поле где мой URL виден только адресс сайта, а не моя ссылка</p>
 <p><font color = blue>Ответ:</font> Это добавлено чтобы не засорять строку, на самом деле при серфе находится <font color = red>ВАШ</font> URL</p>
 <p><font color = red>Вопрос:</font> Сколько ваш проект собирается прожить? Стоит ли надеяться на дальнейшее сотрудничество?</p>
 <p><font color = blue>Ответ:</font> Да мы будем жить очень долго, и верно т.к мы ничего не теряем, и закрывать такой проект не вижу смысла</p>
"
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне нужно изменить его так чтобы фон стал не белым на например #8FBC8F. Не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body style="background: #8FBC8F">
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё разобрался.